# Is there a direct way to show Fano surface of lines and conics on the pairs of Fano threefolds isomorphic?

Tags: derived-categories, birational-geometry, hodge-theory, hilbert-schemes, fano-varieties

I am considering the following setting:

Let $(Y_d, X_{4d+2})$ be the pair of degree $d$ and index 2 Fano threefold $Y_d$ and degree $4d+2$ index 1 Fano threefold and both of them are Picard number 1. Let $F_l(Y_d), F_c(X_{4d+2})$ be the Fano surface of lines on $Y_d$ and Fano surface of conics on $X_{4d+2}$. Assume that $d=3,4,5$, then it is known(classically) that $Y_d$ is birational to $X_{4d+2}$. It is also known classically that $F_l(Y_d)\cong F_c(X_{4d+2})$ for $d=3,4,5$. In particular $F_l(Y_5)\cong F_c(X_{22})\cong\mathbb{P}^2$, $F_l(Y_4)\cong F_c(X_{18})\cong J(\Gamma)$, which is a Jacobian of degree $7$ genus $2$ curve and $F_l(Y_3)\cong F_c(X_{14})$, which is a smooth irreducible general type surface.

**Question**  Is there a straightforward way to prove that $F_l(Y_d)\cong F_c(X_{4d+2})$, for $d=3,4,5$? I am hoping that there is an argument going like this: the explicitly constructed birational isomorphism from $Y_d$ to $X_{4d+2}$ will induce a map  $F_l(Y_d)\rightarrow F_c(X_{4d+2})$ and vice versa, then at least the numerical invariants those two surfaces could be compared. There is a construction contained in the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.3670.pdf of O. DEBARRE, A. ILIEV, AND L. MANIVEL, they show that

(**Proposition 7.4**) A general quartic double solid $Y_2$ is birational to a 2-
dimensional family of nodal Fano threefolds $\widetilde{X}_{10}$ which are degenerations of
(smooth) Fano threefolds of type $\mathcal{X}_{10}$

The map they constructed produces a map $F_l(Y_2)\rightarrow F_c(\widetilde{X}_{10})$. I am not sure whether people had tried to prove the isomorphim of the pair of Fano surfaces for $d=3,4,5$ in this way.
Of course, for any smooth quartic double solid and general smooth ordinary Gushel-Mukai, their Fano surfaces are not isomorphic to each other.

I am aware that there is work of A.Kuznetsov Y.Prokhorov and C.A.Shramov to prove those identification via Kuznetsov's conjecture for $d=3,4,5$(which is known). But my motivation is to understand Kuznetsov conjecture, so I can not assume that it is true(Although it is true for $d=3,4,5$).